# Even after delete subsite, search still shows results from deleted site

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

Even after delete subsite, search still shows results from deleted site. How to overcome this?

Comment: Hi Sam, did below answer helped?

Answer (score 5):

**You will need to perform full crawl. This will remove deleted sites from search.**

To crawl content that is defined in a particular content source, take the following steps:

1. Go to **Central Administration** and then to **Search Service application**.
2. On the Search Administration page, under Crawl, click **Content sources**.
3. On the Manage Content Sources page, point to the content source you want to crawl, click the arrow that appears, and then click **Start Full Crawl** on the menu that appears.

**NOTE:** The value in the Status column changes to Crawling Full for the content source you selected in this step.

Repeat step 3 for each content source for which you want to do a full crawl.

**NOTE:**  The value in the Status column on the page does not automatically change when the crawl is completed. To update the Status column, you must refresh the Manage Content Sources page by clicking Refresh.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Start-a-full-crawl-5028b713-5f81-4729-b2c1-88f2c46ae09d